# Как указать параметры при вызове камеры?

Tags: java, android

Если вызвать камеру через Intent, и перед нажатием на кнопку "Сделать снимок" зайти в настройки, то там будет сокращенный список.

Как сделать, чтобы этот список был полный?

Мне надо в нем включить разрешение использовать координаты геолокации.

Делаю так:

```
private Uri selectedPhotoPath;
Intent captureIntent;
captureIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedPhotoPath);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            captureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "A photo", selectedPhotoPath);
            captureIntent.setClipData(clip);
            captureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
        int permissionStatus = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (permissionStatus == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startActivityForResult(captureIntent, RESULT_CAMERA);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что никак. Смысл в том, что есть настройки камеры, которые влияют на идентификацию, в частности геотаггинг - предполагается, что юзер должен включать/выключать их сам своими рученьками. Вторжение сюда через "заднюю дверь" - программно рассматривается как вторжение в личное пространство юзера.

**Update**

Также отсутствует возможность вызова настроек камеры, по крайней мере уважаемый @CommonsWare [именно так и говорит](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44178344/472270)

Comment: Так именно эту возможность "включить руками" и надо вывести.

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. На сегодня: Sumsung A10 - позволяет включить, Blackview - включил программно, Redmi 8A - пока не обойти, но буду копать дальше.